# .replace() method in Java replaces what is replaced

Tags: java, string, methods

Below is my code. I am trying to input "ATC" to get an output of "UAG".
All it does is replace 'A' with 'U', 'T' with 'A', 'C' with 'G', and 'G' with 'C' (Just like transcription - DNA to mRNA).

The problem is... when I input ATC, AGC, TGC, or anything with 'C' at the end, the program will replace 'C' with 'G' and then proceed to replace the new 'G' with a 'C'.

`.replace('C','G').replace('G','C');`

How can I stop the program from replacing the 'C' back to a 'C'?
**My input should be AGC, and the intended output should be UCG.**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String codon = scanner.next();

            String basePairing = codon
                    .replace('A','U').replace('T','A')
                    .replace('C','G').replace('G','C');
            System.out.println(basePairing);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String codon = scanner.next();             /*ATGC*/
char[] codonArr = codon.toCharArray();
for (int i=0;i<codonArr.length;i++)
{
     switch(codonArr[i])
     {              
        case 'A': {codonArr[i]='U';break;}
        case 'T': {codonArr[i]='A';break;}
        case 'C': {codonArr[i]='G';break;}
        case 'G': {codonArr[i]='C';break;}
     }
}
        
codon = new String(codonArr);
System.out.println(codon);                 /*UACG*/
```

*In* :    **`ATGC`**

*Out*: **`UACG`**

Comment: If your scanner input is longer or this algorithm later on will accept longer text, I strongly advise considering using StringBuilder (a lot faster) oder StringBuffer (fast and thread-safe)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by conditional branching and by using [`String#replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) as shown below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String codon = scanner.next();

        String basePairing = codon.contains("G")?
                                codon.replace('A','U').replace('T','A')
                                .replace('C','G').replaceFirst("G", "C"):
                                        codon.replace('A','U').replace('T','A')
                                        .replace('C','G');
        System.out.println(basePairing);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
AGC
UCG
```

**Another sample run:**

```
ATC
UAG
```

Comment: [aran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2148953/aran) had also written a solution which I was about to go through before he deleted his answer. I really like his answers. Probably he deleted because someone had down-voted his answer without leaving a comment.

Comment: This is not really a solution. It seem to focus only on the example inputs, i.e. `replaceFirst` wouldn’t work with repeated occurrences. But even for three-letter inputs without repetition, it’s not handling all cases. What if the input is `"CGA"`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little **characterSwap()** method you may find useful:

```
public static String characterSwap(String inputString, Character... characters) {
    if (characters.length == 0 || characters.length % 2 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("characterSwap() Method Error! "
                    + "Invalid parameter pairing for characters swapping!");
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
        Character curChar = inputString.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < characters.length; j += 2) {
            if (characters[j] != null && curChar.equals(characters[j])) {
                curChar = characters[j + 1];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (curChar != null && curChar != 0) {
            sb.append(curChar.toString());
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

To use it:

```
String str = characterSwap("ATC, AGC, TGC", 'A', 'U', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'C');
System.out.println(str);
```

Any 'A' encountered is replaced with 'U', any 'T' encountered is replaced with 'A', any 'C' encountered is replaced with 'G', and any 'G' encountered is replaced with 'C'.

The console output will be:

```
UAG, UCG, ACG
```

The swap characters can be provided as a Character[] array as well. If you want to remove a specific character then pass `null` or `'\0'` in your character swapping pairs, for example:

```
String str = characterSwap("ATC, AGC, TGC", 'A', 'U', 'T', null, 'C', 'G', 'G', 'C');
```

Here, when a 'T' is encountered, it is removed.

The console output will be:

```
UG, UCG, CG
```

Comment: You are still not filtering. Since `'\0'`, `'\u0000'`, and `0` are just different ways to denote the same value, the checks are redundant and have no effect, as long as you still insert the character in the result string. Just use `if(curChar == characters[j]) { Character replace = characters[j + 1]; if(replace != null && replace != 0) { sb.append(replace); } break; }`

Comment: @Holger, Thank you so much for your assistance and...patience. If there are any more issues with this I'll just delete it.

Comment: No need to delete, it’s correct now. However, if you used the nested `if` as in my suggestion, you could keep `curChar` as `char` and could use `==` instead of `equals` and don’t need call `toString()` on it. And instead of `new StringBuilder("")`, I’d use `new StringBuilder(inputString.length())`, to give it an appropriate initial capacity (it’s initially empty anyway). But these are all just slight performance improvements, as said, it’s correct now.